# Два разных сабмита из одной формы

Tags: jquery, ajax

Есть одна форма: логин + пароль. Работает с использованием ajax.
Стоит задача: человек ввел логин, нажал отправить. на сервере происходит определенная обработка и возвращается ответ. Если ответ положительный, то человек должен ввести пароль и отправить запрос.
Дело в том, что запрос от первого сабмита и второго должны уходить на разные скрипты. Это возможно или одна форма  - один вариант сабмита?

Comment: если вы запросы аяксом отправляете, то форма тут вообще не нужна

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы плохо разобрались с *jQuery* и *Ajax*, раз у Вас возникают такие вопросы.

jQuery *умеет* сериализовать форму, а также умеет и *доставать* значения из указанного элемента.

Предлагаю Вам рассмотреть два варианта решения проблемы.

#### Сериализация формы

---

jQuery умеет *сериализовать* формы двумя способами:

1. в [query string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) - [ссылка](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/).
2. в виде JS массива - [ссылка](https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/).

Пусть есть следующая форма:

```
<form id="form">
   <input type="text" name="login">
   <input type="password" name="password">
   <input type="submit" value="login" id="form-btn">
</form>
```

1.Используем jQuery для сериализации в виде *query string* и отправки формы:

```
<script>
    $('#form-btn').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var serializeStr = $('#form').serialize();
        /*
        * Сериализованная строка имеет вид:
        * login=InputLogin&password=InputPassword
        * то есть идеально подходит для query-параметров (те параметры,
        * которые используются в URL при GET-запросе).
        */
        var actionUrl = '/url/to/get-action?' + serializeStr;
        var httpMethod = 'GET';
        $.ajax({
           method: httpMethod,
           url: actionUrl,
           success: function(response) {
               alert("success: " + response);
           },
           error: function(xhr, data, status) {
               alert("error: " + data);
           }             
        });
    });
</script>
```

Идеально подходит для отправки запросов методом **GET**.

2.Используем jQuery для сериализации в виде *query string* и отправки формы:

```
<script>
    $('#form-btn').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var serializeData = $('#form').serializeArray();
        /*
        * Результат сериализации имеет вид:
        * [
        *  {
        *    name:"login",
        *    value:"inputLogin"
        *  },
        *  {
        *    name:"password",
        *    value:"inputPassword"
        *  },
        *  .....
        * ], 
        * то есть идеально подходит для POST-параметров.
        */
        var actionUrl = '/url/to/post-action';
        var httpMethod = 'POST';
        $.ajax({
           method: httpMethod,
           url: actionUrl,
           data: serializeData,
           success: function(response) {
               alert("success: " + response);
           },
           error: function(xhr, data, status) {
               alert("error: " + data);
           }             
        });
    });
</script>
```

Плюсы:

- меньше проблем с составлением отправляемых параметров (особенно в случае с *serialize()*;
- если форма имеет большое к-ство вводимых данных - значительно
  экономит время.

Минусы:

- в случае с *serializeArray()* недостаточно гибко создает параметры (на стороне сервера их будет не очень удобно перебирать);
- если нужно отправлять данные на разные *action'ы*, то необходимо разбивать и оборачивать их (данные) в разные формы для сериализации.

#### Достаем данные из HTML-элементов:

---

Пусть мы имеем следующую структуру HTML-документа:

```
<div id="custom-form">
   <div class="custom-form-element">
     <input id="login" type="text">
   </div>
   <div class="custom-form-element">
     <input id="password" type="password">
   </div>
   <div class="custom-form-button">
     <button id="custom-form-btn">Login</button>
   </div>
</div>
```

На самом деле, предоставленный код выше может быть и формой, но для наглядности - в этом случае формы использовать не будем.

Используем jQuery для отправки данных на сервер:

```
<script>
   $('#custom-form-btn').on('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();

      var urlLogin = 'path/to/login-action';
      var urlPassword = 'path/to/password-action';

      var login = $('#login').val();
      var password = $('#password').val();

      var loginData = {
         login: login
      }

      var passwordData = {
         password: password
      }

      sendAjax(urlLogin, loginData);
      sendAjax(urlPassword, passwordData);
   });

   function sendAjax(url, data) {
      $.ajax({
         url: url,
         method: 'POST',
         data: data,
         success: function(response) {
            alert('Success: ' + response);
         },
         error: function(xhr, data, status) {
            alert('Error: ' + data);
         }
      });
</script>
```

И так, выборка данных из HTML-элементов происходит вызова метода [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/). На самом деле, метод умеет не только выбирать данные, но и устанавливать их в элемент (сейчас нас это не интересует).

Метод `val()` можно вызвать на элементах, позволяющих вводить данные (*input/select/textarea/etc*).

Если вам понадобиться достать данные из других HTML-элементов (таких как `<p></p>, <span></span>` etc) можете воспользоваться следующими методами:

- [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/);
- [`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/);

Плюсы:

- очень гибкое решение для формирования данных;
- удобно разбивать данные не по HTML-формах, а в JS-коде;
- более читаемо в коде.

Минусы:

- если данных на форме (в современных реалиях форма - не обязательно `<form></form>`) много - формирование данных будет занимать некоторое время.